# Limiting title characters in the AZIndex plugin

Tags: plugins

I am using the [AZIndex plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/azindex/) to list post titles in my site and i would now like to limit the title characters, how would i do that?

Comment: some good grammar and punctuation might help you get more answers :)

Comment: I've taken the liberty of rewording the question and title to make things clearer, but i do have a question. Are you open to modifying the plugin or are you looking for an alternative method, ie. something you can do from your theme functions file? (not that the second is necessarily possible, but it helps to know your expectations).

Answer (score 1):

Look for any function in the plugin code like truncate or strLen that could be cutting your titles or limiting their number of chars.